# How can I free() after strdup?

Tags: c

How can I `free()` from `strdup` when the call looked like this: `*(result + idx++) = strdup(token);`?

More context:

```
char **str_split(char *a[], char *a_str, const char a_delim) {
    char **result = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    char *tmp = a_str;
    char *last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp) {
        if (a_delim == *tmp) {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char *) * count);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
        return result; //return with failure
    }

    if (result) {
        size_t idx = 0;
        char *token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token) {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token); /* memory leak! how to free() */
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `result[idx++]` was too understandable I presume?

Comment: `delim[0]` and `delim[1]` are used, so array index operator shouldn't be banned.

Comment: The code that calls this function will need to call `free` on all the stored pointers once it has finished with them

Comment: @MikeCAT: Actually the index-operator works on a pointer and never an array anyway.

Comment: @Olaf [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) says "6.5.2.1 Array subscripting", not "Pointer subscripting"

Comment: @MikeCAT: Yes, it is **called** like that. I did not doubt that. But before it is applied, the array is converted to a pointer (to the first element). Which it the reason you can write `5[array]`. See p2 in the same section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*(result + idx) = 0;` line makes it possible to tell where is the end of the sequence.
Just `free()` all elements allocated after finished using them.
Also the array to store itself should be `free()`d after finished being used.

```
char ** ret = char **str_split(/* some arguments */);
size_t idx;

/* deal with the result */

for (idx = 0; *(ret + idx) != NULL; idx++) {
    free(*(ret + idx));
}
free(ret);
```

Comment: Better style to use `ret[idx]` than `*(ret + idx)`

Comment: Now it works. My case looks like `for (idx = 0; *(dealloc[f] + idx) != NULL; idx++) {` because I had an array.

Answer (score 1):

When it's done with `result`, the code that calls this function will have to `free` every pointer in `result` and then `free` result itself.